# Wicket boolean model

Tags: java, model, wicket

I want to create an ajaxcheckbox without wiring it to a class attribute using propertymodel. Why does the code in the example not work? The boolean value doesnt change when the user checks or unchecks the checkbox.

```
boolean show = false;
AjaxCheckBox showBox = new AjaxCheckBox("showBox", new Model<Boolean>(show)){
    //onUpdate stuff
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boolean value will not change because the `showBox` does not have a reference to the original variable `show`.  You just initialized the `showBox` model with false.  The code you have there is equivalent to:

```
AjaxCheckBox showBox = new AjaxCheckBox("showBox", new Model<Boolean>(false)){
    //onUpdate stuff
};
```

If you want to access the model value of the `showBox` you can use `getModelObject()`, which will return the boolean value stored in the `AjaxCheckBox`'s model.

Models are complex in wicket - but very powerful.

To illustrate further, `Model` keeps its own reference to a value.  `PropertyModel` keeps a reference to a different object, and then stores the value in the property of that object.  Look at the source code of `Model` and you'll see it is very simple.